# How Can I get the variable from Smarty 3 template to the PHP?

Tags: php, smarty

In php file use Smarty 3 function **getTemplateVars()**:

```
$MyGetVar = $this->Smarty->getTemplateVars('smarty_variable_in_template');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean passing the variable from php to the template?

```
$this->Smarty->assign('variablename', 'value');
```

Comment: No, get template vars from smarty template!

Comment: Generally the template displaying is the last step of the server side processing. I this case php code already ran, it won't see. If you call something php inside a template for example through a plugin, then you can pass parameters to the plugin.

Comment: Maybe this function can help: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl